# Switching order of HTML elements when layout changes in Responsive Web Design

Tags: html, css

I am building a responsive website, and for good user experience, I need some layout changes from mobile to desktop. Specifically, I need to switch the order of some HTML elements.

I need HTML elements be in a different order for desktop vs mobile.

**Mobile**

```
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
```

**Order switched for Desktop**

```
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="three">Three</div>
<div class="two">Two</div>
```

This is simplified version of what I want to accomplish. I think it's called [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). How do web design experts move html elements around? With JavaScript? Would it be normal? Are there any jQuery plugins?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use jQuery to change the DOM around as required

```
if (mobile == true) {

    $('div.three').insertBefore($('div.two'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just wasn't sure if this is a good practice. In my particular case, If I were to manipulate the DOM, then HTML5 outline was affected the way I didn't want. It seems like I have to choose between good visual user experience that fulfills the need of business and well structured HTML5 outline.

Comment: shouldn't the example read `$('div.3')...` instead of `three`?

Comment: Only if you want invalid CSS... :) http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Comment: If the `mobile` variable is set based on the viewport, a resize handler and additional code to reverse the order is needed. You would now be better of using `flexbox` and `order`: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on your layout there will be a number of ways of achieving this. If your divs are stacking side by side on the desktop and vertically on mobile you might be able to use a combination of floats and media queries to get them displaying in the right order.

If not your final fallback might be to create 4 divs.

```
<div>one</div>
<div>three(mobile)</div>
<div>two</div>
<div>three(desktop)</div>
```

Then use media queries to hide the relevant "three" div depending on the device.

Comment: Wouldn't this method be bad practice from a performance point of view? The mobile DOM would be bloated by hidden content.

Comment: On my opinion there's nothing bad to have an extra div in that case, rather then use js for such a small thing.

Answer (score 12):

Resurrecting this question because i came across it via google, and the existing answers are outdated.  The solution i ended up using was the [only one with the downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19965881/2379542), so i'll elaborate on it.

Using `display:flex` will allow you to re-order elements using the `column`/`column-reverse` properties:

```
.container{ display:flex;flex-direction:column }
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .container{ flex-direction:column-reverse }
}
```

See the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/as6d6zas/), and some support tables [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Aflex).

Also check out a couple CSS post-processors [here](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer)

Comment: and if you want the elements to be side-by-side you can use `flex-direction` with `row` and `row-reverse`.

Comment: You can even mix them together and have the elements be side-by-side in one case, and on top of each other in another case.

Comment: SInce the OP wanted to switch to a non-sequential order in desktop (1, 3, 2), flex's `order` property on the children would come in handy for that purpose. Accessibility note, however: screen readers all currently read things in the DOM order, ignoring `order` changes via CSS.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by jquery  what you need to do is check the device and insert according to it

also its good to read responsive webdesign where you will learn stuff like that check this qustion [Responsive Web Design Tips, Best Practices and Dynamic Image Scaling Techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429058/responsive-web-design-tips-best-practices-and-dynamic-image-scaling-techniques)

i found here good tips and also check this

1. [Beginner’s Guide to Responsive Web Design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)
2. [Responsive Web Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will stack the div in mobile and on desktop it would be a 2 column layout

```
<div class="main">

</div>
<div class="aside">
</div>

<style type="text/css">
   @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .main {float:right;width:60%}
      .aside {float:left;width:40%}
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with: 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: Could you pull the relevant information from the linked page and post it in the answer? If the linked page changes, then this answer becomes much less valuable.