# Why minimizing the window causing the HTML elements to disappear from the parent container itself?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code with me. I have duly tried to centrally align the parent container div `#header` and the childs within it `#header1` and `#header2` respectively. But when I try to minimize the window the parent container seems not to be centrally aligned and moreover the child headers seems to be collapsed even after setting the width explicitly to `width:50%;` of the parent container. Why is it so? Please explain and help me fix this. Also note the horizontal navigation bar below it also seems to be associated with the same bug I mentioned above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style>
    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header {
        margin:10px auto;
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        height:80px;    
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
    }
    #header1 {  
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;           
    }
    #header2 {
        display:inline-block;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    #navmenu {
        list-style-type:none;
        background-color:#444;
        border:black 2px solid;         
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    #content {
    }
    #nav {
    }
    #navmenu li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        width:33%;
        display:inline-block
    }
    #navmenu li a {
        text-decoration:none;           
        display:block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !! </h1></div>           
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li><li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should create a jsFiddle or a snippet so we can see the problem faster and help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed height on `#header` prevented the text to be visible on smaller screens as there isn't enough space. I removed it so the height is dynamic.

Also added some margin left and right of `#header1` and `#header2` so they don't stick to eachother.

The horizontal menu items collapsing can be fixed with `box-sizing`, and `width: 33.33%`

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2dj9kkj/)

More info on box-sizing can be found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have `display: inline-block` in both elements `#header1` and `#header2`, so that's actually expected behavior in HTML. I changed `display:inline-block` for `float: left;` in both elements, but you still will need to make more changes to get the desired look. If yoy want the website responsive, you should check some tutorials about [Responsive Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429058/responsive-web-design-tips-best-practices-and-dynamic-image-scaling-techniques) and [Media Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

```css
*{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }  
    <!--Resetter rules for browsers-->
    #bodyContainer {
    }
    body {
        border:black 2px solid;
        background-color : grey;
        padding:5px;
    }
    #header {
        margin:10px auto;
        background-color : red;
        width:70%;
        height:80px;    
        -webkit-border-radius:15px;
        -moz-border-radius:15px;
        border-radius:15px;
    }
    #header1 {  
        float: left;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;           
    }
    #header2 {
        float: left;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:80px;
    }
    #navmenu {
        list-style-type:none;
        background-color:#444;
        border:black 2px solid;         
        text-align:center;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }
    #content {
    }
    #nav {
    }
    #navmenu li {
        border:black 1px solid;
        background:yellow;
        border-radius:5px;
        height:30px;
        line-height:30px;
        width:33%;
        display:inline-block
    }
    #navmenu li a {
        text-decoration:none;           
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="bodyContainer">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header1"><h1>Welcome</h1></div><div id="header2"><h1>You Get to choose better !! </h1></div>           
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentHeader">
            <p>You Select ... We Serve </p>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul id="navmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li><li><a href="#">Fashions</a></li>                  
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>WebApp Version Numbered v1.0. All rights Reserved. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```