# How are they making this instagram respond like div blocks

Tags: css, responsive-design, instagram

My experience so far has just been getting an instagram feed to embed with set columns and rows, but I was looking at beardbrand.com, and they have their instagram feed set to be responsive and change column and row configuration based on screen size.  Has anyone seen this before, or know how the code is written to make it responsive in this form, rather than the images simply shrinking and expanding based on screen size?

Comment: You can use media queries to alter the look of the feed based on screen size. It should be relatively easy as Instagram pictures are usually square shaped to begin with. You can just set a fixed width and height and float everything left.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429058/responsive-web-design-tips-best-practices-and-dynamic-image-scaling-techniques) a pretty good question on how to make a responsive design.